# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'context'

Tags: django, testing

I get the following error when I try to run a pyVows test:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\Programmierung\Python-Projekte\JourneyMap\JourneyMap\tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django_pyvows.context import DjangoHTTPContext
  File "C:\Users\malo0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django_pyvows\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from context import DjangoContext, DjangoHTTPContext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'context'
```

I installed `pyVows and django-pyvows` Am I missing something? I found no helpful documentation

**REQUESTED EDIT:**

```
from pyvows import Vows, expect
from django_pyvows.context import DjangoHTTPContext

# Create your tests here.


@Vows.batch
class LanguageTest(Vows.Context):
    class LanguageSelectIntegrationTest(DjangoHTTPContext):
        def topic(self):
            return self.get('/')

        def test(self, topic):
            # Test will be here
            pass
```

Comment: Could you share the code where you import the modules?

Comment: Sure but there is no test at the moment because first I wanted to test if I have every dependency

Comment: This project may not support the newer Django versions. Last commits were made 5 years ago. In requirements.txt the version of Django is 1.11.29 which is pretty old.

Comment: Yeah, already recognized. Error fixed by putting a `.` in front of context inside the `django_pyvows\__init__.py`. Then more errors show up, for example, no `as` inside `except`. Is there another framework to do view integration tests with django?

Comment: Found on developer Mozilla - "Django provides a test framework with a small hierarchy of classes that build on the Python standard unittest library. Despite the name, this test framework is suitable for both unit and integration tests."